# Como mostrar o valor do banco em uma star rating?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Consegui fazer o sistema de star rating, porém eu queria que o voto fosse mostrado na tela ou guardado na estrela, para ela ficar preenchida conforme os votos. Alguém poderia me ajudar, aqui esta meu código:

Essa é a pagina em que estão as estrelas:

```
 <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".vote #stars").click(function () {

       $.post('rating.php',{rate:$(this).val()},function(d){
                     if(d>0)
                        {
                          alert('Seu voto Ja foi confirmado');
                          }else{
                          alert('Obrigado por Votar');
                        }
                    });
                 $(this).attr("checked");
              });
          });
 </script>
<div class="vote">
<label>
    <input id="stars" type="radio" name="fb" value="1" />
    <i class="fa" id="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input id="stars" type="radio" name="fb" value="2" />
    <i class="fa" id="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input id="stars" type="radio" name="fb" value="3" />
    <i class="fa" id="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input id="stars" type="radio" name="fb" value="4" />
    <i class="fa" id="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input id="stars" type="radio" name="fb" value="5" />
    <i class="fa" id="fa"></i>
</label>
</div>
```

Aqui o script para o `hover` nas estrelas e para marcá-las como `actives`:

```
$('.vote label i.fa').on('click mouseover',function(){
    // remove classe ativa de todas as estrelas
    $('.vote label i.fa').removeClass('active');
    // pegar o valor do input da estrela clicada
    var val = $(this).prev('input').val();
    //percorrer todas as estrelas
    $('.vote label i.fa').each(function(){
        /* checar de o valor clicado é menor ou igual do input atual
        *  se sim, adicionar classe active
        */
        var $input = $(this).prev('input');
        if($input.val() <= val){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
    $("#voto").html(val); // somente para teste
});
//Ao sair da div vote
$('.vote').mouseleave(function(){
    //pegar o valor clicado
    var val = $(this).find('input:checked').val();
    //se nenhum foi clicado remover classe de todos
    if(val == undefined ){
        $('.vote label i.fa').removeClass('active');
    } else { 
        //percorrer todas as estrelas
        $('.vote label i.fa').each(function(){
            /* Testar o input atual do laço com o valor clicado
            *  se maior, remover classe, senão adicionar classe
            */
            var $input = $(this).prev('input');
            if($input.val() > val){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
    $("#voto").html(val); // somente para teste
});
```

E esta é a pagina rating em PHP. Eu queria que o usuário pudesse votar mais de uma vez nela, mas não estou conseguindo. Obs: Essa parte do banco em PHP eu fiz seguindo um tutorial em inglês e estou tentando fazer ele não bloquear o voto para somente uma pessoa.

```
<?php 
$ipaddress = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); // here I am taking IP as UniqueID but you can have user_id from Database or SESSION

$servername = "localhost"; // Server details
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "filmes";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Unable to connect Server: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['rate']) && !empty($_POST['rate'])) {

    $rate = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['rate']);
// check if user has already rated
    $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_rating` WHERE `user_id`='" . $ipaddress . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo $row['id'];
    } else {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_rating` ( `rate`, `user_id`) VALUES ('" . $rate . "', '" . $ipaddress . "'); ";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "0";
        }
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Um usuário pode votar varias vezes no mesmo conteúdo? Sua duvida é em mostrar o voto do usuário com as estrelas, ou fazer a média geral?

Comment: eu preciso da media geral para mostrar isso que eu quero fazer desculpe se nao fui claro na pergunta mas quero fazer a media geral e depois recuperar os votos e mostrar na estrelas conforme a media de votos que o artigo ira ter. e sim eu quero que o usuario possa votar mais de uma vez

Comment: Se entendi certo, você terá uma query com `AVG( rate )` para calcular a média geral, e uma query com a lista de todos os votos: ( user1 - ★★★☆☆, user2 - ★★★★★ )...

Comment: como eu posso implementar isso no meu projeto?

Comment: Você só colocou o `INSERT` na questão, mostre o `SELECT` onde você recupera os votos.

Comment: nao fiz o select para recuperar mas posso faze-lo quando eu fazer o select para recuperar eu tenho q jogar a onde o o valor do rating que eu recuperar? eu dou select na tabela where rate e onde eu jogo esse valor que foi salvo para mostrar no html? mas tambem tenho q fazer o calculo onde implementalo?

Comment: Exemplo: `select AVG( rate ) as rate from tbl_rating where id = 1` essa consulta vai retornar um índice com a média total de votos.

Comment: amigo se voce reparar eu tenho um select na parte em php que esta pegando o id do usuario eu ja troquei para ele pegar o campo rate que e onde estao os votos e ficou assim: $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_rating` WHERE `rate`='" . $rate . "'"; agora como que eu faco o calculo e depois chamo ele no html para ficar mostrando a quantidade de votos que aquele artigo teve?

Comment: Conseguiu Resolver?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89133/129

Comment: Vamos por partes, para o usuário vota mais de uma vez remove a verificação de que ele já votou:  `$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_rating` WHERE `user_id`='" . $ipaddress . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo $row['id'];
    } else {`

Answer (score -3):

Amigo faz o seguinte vc quer que possa votar mais de uma vez não?
Se sim crie um botão onde sera enviado o id do usuario para uma tabela que sera domado +1 aos votos já existente

```
input type="submit" name ="voto" value="<?php // PEGUE O ID DO USUARIO ?>"/

//vou fazer com PHP estrutural
$id =  $_POST['voto'];

$voltar = $volta($id);

function volta($id){

$sql = "SELECT FROM tbl_name WHERE id_user = '$id'"
$resul = pg_query($sua_conexao, $sql);
$voltar = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
return $voltar;

}

votar();

function votar($id){
global $voltar;
$nvoto = $voltar['voto'] + 1;
sql = "INSERT INTO nome_tabela(id_user,voto) values('$id','$voto')";
$resultar = pg_query($sua_conexao, $sql);
$pg_close($sua_conexao);

}
```

Fiz com Posts e não testei, mas espero que você tenha entendido a lógica se precisar em POO e PDO posso refazer de uma forma mais legal